# Android Issue with db Save Same Name And NULL value in DataBase

Tags: android, mysql

I have made a database it save same name and also null value in db.i want that when i enter name and other value if name is already exist in database it show Toast and in Toast show that name is Already exist and do not save value .also when all value is null and i press save it show toast please insert info. anybody help me to solve this problem.No reply

```
    < public class FoodDbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "MY_Calorie_DISH.DB";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    private static final String CREATE_QUERY =
            "CREATE TABLE "+ Food.NewDishInfo.TABLE_NAME+"("
                    + Food.NewDishInfo.DISH_NAME+" TEXT NOT NULL,"
                    + Food.NewDishInfo.DISH_QUANTITY+" TEXT NOT NULL,"
                    + Food.NewDishInfo.DISH_CALORIE+" INTEGER NOT NULL,"
                    + Food.NewDishInfo.DISH_FAT+" TEXT NOT NULL,"
                    + Food.NewDishInfo.DISH_PROTEIN+" TEXT NOT NULL,"
                    + Food.NewDishInfo.DISH_SUGAR+" TEXT NOT NULL,"
                    + Food.NewDishInfo.DISH_VITAMINS+" TEXT NOT NULL);";
    public FoodDbHelper(Context context)
    {
        super(context,DATABASE_NAME,null,DATABASE_VERSION);
        Log.e("DATABASE OPERATION","Database created / opened...");
    }
    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL(CREATE_QUERY);
        Log.e("DATABASE OPERATION","Table created...");
    }
    public void addInformations(String name ,String quantity, Integer calorie, String fat ,
                                String protein,String sugar,String vitamins, SQLiteDatabase db){


        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(Food.NewDishInfo.DISH_NAME,name);
        contentValues.put(Food.NewDishInfo.DISH_QUANTITY,quantity);
        contentValues.put(Food.NewDishInfo.DISH_CALORIE,calorie);
        contentValues.put(Food.NewDishInfo.DISH_FAT,fat);
        contentValues.put(Food.NewDishInfo.DISH_PROTEIN,protein);
        contentValues.put(Food.NewDishInfo.DISH_SUGAR,sugar);
        contentValues.put(Food.NewDishInfo.DISH_VITAMINS,vitamins);
        db.insert(Food.NewDishInfo.TABLE_NAME, null, contentValues);
        Log.e("DATABASE OPERATION","one row inserted...");
    } 
   @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

    }
} >
```

//
this is my data insert activity

```
     <public class AddNewDish extends Activity {

    EditText name, quantity, calorie, fat, protein, sugar, vitamins;
    Context context = this;
    FoodDbHelper foodDbHelper;
    SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_new_dish);


        name = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.dish_name);
        quantity = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.dish_quantity);

        calorie = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.dish_calorie);
        fat = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.dish_fat);
        protein = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.dish_protein);
        sugar = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.dish_sugar);
        vitamins = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.dish_vitamins);
    }

    public void addDish(View view) {

        String dish_name = name.getText().toString();
        String dish_quantity = quantity.getText().toString();
        Integer dish_calorie = Integer.valueOf(calorie.getText().toString());
        String dish_fat = fat.getText().toString();
        String dish_protein = protein.getText().toString();
        String dish_sugar = sugar.getText().toString();
        String dish_vitamins = vitamins.getText().toString();


        foodDbHelper = new FoodDbHelper(context);
        sqLiteDatabase = foodDbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        foodDbHelper.addInformations(dish_name, dish_quantity, dish_calorie, dish_fat, 
                dish_protein, dish_sugar, dish_vitamins, sqLiteDatabase);
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Data Saved", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        foodDbHelper.close();
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, AddNewDish.class);
        startActivity(intent);


    }




    public void AllDish(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, DataListActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }


    public void goback(View view)
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this,MainMenu.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}>
```

//thanks in advance